# Oracle OS networking: ping neither success nor fails

Tags: linux-networking

I have an Oracle OS which is trying to connect to internet. But the problem is that all network configs are set correctly bu I can not ping any thing at all.
this is the config:

```
dmesg |grep eth
pcnet32: eth0: registered as PCnet/PCI II 79C970A
pcnet32 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link up
pcnet32 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link up
pcnet32 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link up
pcnet32 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link up
```

Another command:

```
ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:EE:02:B2
          inet addr:10.0.0.150  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:feee:2b2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:673065 errors:0 dropped:210 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4864 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:49858456 (47.5 MiB)  TX bytes:556786 (543.7 KiB)
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0x2000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:288600 (281.8 KiB)  TX bytes:288600 (281.8 KiB)
```

And the last:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.0.0.10
nameserver 77.104.106.2
```

I can ping another computer in the network and DNS server and default gw works fine for my own pc Win7. But I can not connect to the internet. I mean when I ping sth like 8.8.4.4 after a long time it neither return error message no success message and I should stop it by myself and after stopping it tells that many packets have been sent without any response. Anybody can help me plz?

Edit: here is another command as requested:

```
ip route show
default via 10.0.0.60 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.150
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
```

Why are you voting to close it?!?! at least comment your opinion about this question for me to understand the problem

Edit: another settings:

```
iptables -L -n | grep icmp
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

our company has closed the ability to ping 4.4.4.4 but I can ping 8.8.4.4 on my PC which is not answering in Linux server. It show this without any other response:

```
ping 8.8.4.4
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

and if I cancel the request it show such a message:

```
--- 8.8.4.4 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4482ms
```

and also my linux does not understand `tshark` command

Comment: You want to use `ping -O 8.8.8.8` this makes ping behave incorrectly just like its windows counterpart

Comment: @Anubioz -O is not recognized by my ping!

Comment: Displaying lost packets was added to ping/iputils back in 2012, while your OS uses version from 2007. You are out of options besides using a better linux distro, since there is no way to update iputils without messing everything on package based distributions...

Comment: @Anubioz Is the connection problem related to the version? I am using Oracle OS v6.5

Comment: Try `ip link set eth0 address <mac address of your home pc, which works in this network>`